VSCode shows duplicate tests in Python
I don't know if this due to a recent update, but I am seeing my Python tests appear twice and when I am in test debug mode it runs twice as well. How can I fix this? I just created an empty project and I am running into the same issue.
Steps to reproduce:

python -m venv .venv (create virtualenv)

source ./.venv/bin/activate (activate virtualenv)

pip install pytest==8.3.3

On VSCode select Python interpreter to be the virtualenv one.

mkdir server server/tests

Basic tests file
# server/tests/test_storage.py
import pytest

class TestStorage:
    def test(self):
        pass


Settings.json (I tried different variations with the directory)
{
  "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
    "tests"
  ],
  "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
  "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true
}






VSCode Version: 1.94.0 (Universal)

I was unable to reproduce the issue following your steps. Would you like to try run pytest in terminal and try run py.test --collect-only to see how many tests are detected by pytest and share the output here?

Thanks for trying to replicate!
I ran pytest --collect-only and it correctly gathered the only test. I am also seeing 4 debugger profiles selected, would it have anything to do with that? (I tried setting it to one only but that didn't make a difference, uploaded image of that.)

It seems that VSCode is taking multiple test configurations at the same time.I will suggest submit an issue on vscode-python github homepage.

Thanks for that suggestion - I created the issue: https://github.com/kondratyev-nv/vscode-python-test-adapter/issues/316

It turns out this was due to having both Python and Python Test Explorer for Visual Studio Code extensions enabled, both of them have test functionality. Disabling the latter fixed the issue.

Glad to hear that you fixed the issue! Would you mind marking this as the answer?
